# How to delete a entire row if a cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel

i am having an Excel where data starts from range A8 (column) with other values in their respective columns . I have tried but failed several time a code which will start reading values in each cell of columnn A8 and if found a cell with no value it should delete that entire row. Kindly help

Comment: Try `EmptyCell.EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: Sorry A8 means data starts from A8 cell

Answer (score 0):

As **Tony** suggested:

```
Sub ClearA()
    Dim N As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = Range("A8:A" & N)
    Set r2 = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Intersect(r1, r2).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```